# FindBy method returnign all records in PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, findby

Im using a findBy method in a interface that extends PagingAndSortingRepository. This method is:

```
public List<MyType> findByClassification(String classification);
```

When I invoke this method (myObject.findByClassification("A")), it returns all values and not only records filtered by classification "A".

The class model:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mytype")

public class MyType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer           id;

    private String            name;

    private String            classification;


//getters and setters

}
```

Other find methods work fine:

```
findByClassificationAndName_StartingWith
findByName
```

These methods return only filtered records and not all records in table.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the model class as well?

Comment: Hi Billy, I edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: Try `findByClassificationIs(String classification);`or `findByClassificationEquals(String classification);`